# EXISTS and sub-query cost

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, performance, query-performance

i've just wondered if there's a difference in cost(memory,cpu) of an `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` in following queries. Does it make a difference if i select `NULL`, `1` or columns?

1)

```
SELECT id 
FROM Parent p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT NULL FROM Child c
   WHERE c.parent_Id = p.id
   AND c.x <> c.y
)
```

2)

```
SELECT id 
FROM Parent p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM Child c
   WHERE c.parent_Id = p.id
   AND c.x <> c.y
)
```

3)

```
SELECT id 
FROM Parent p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT * FROM Child c
   WHERE c.parent_Id = p.id
   AND c.x <> c.y
)
```

Option 1 is what i use normally, is there are difference at all or is it optimised to the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should find that each example results in a [LEFT SEMI ANTI JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191171%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with equal costs.

> The Left Anti Semi Join operator returns each row from the first (top)
>   input when there is no matching row in the second (bottom) input. If
>   no join predicate exists in the Argument column, each row is a
>   matching row.

Out of habit I tend to use the syntax in your second example, which you could argue signals intent better than the others.

Comment: Doesn't using the `*` in the third syntax trigger the reading into memory of the entire result-set of the subquery? Thus making it much less efficient because it involves disk read + memory allocation.

Comment: @MihaiStancu No, the optimiser will eliminate that and check for existence of a row only. Given an index on c.parent_id which includes c.x and c.y, you would avoid a lookup to the heap/clustered index.

Comment: As a curiosity does this apply to other db engines such as MYSQL/PGSQL/SQLite?